# Construction Shift

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context, sentence-usage

I need to construction shift this sentence but I have two options in mind that make sense somehow and those two options are options B and D.

There was no remedy available for his constant attacks of asthma, so he suffered severely from respiratory problems.
Begin with "Owing to"
A.therefore he suffered
B. he suffered
C. he would have suffered
D. he had suffered

Comment: Rosie, I mentioned [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/299207/i-need-help-with-this-construction-shift-sentence) and [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/299212/construction-shift-assistance) that you need to show us what work you've done already, and what in particular you're confused about. This site is not for checking your homework